# i'm getting blank object {} in php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have HTML elements like this:

```
   <div id="element">
    <ul>
    <li>
       <a href="#"> apple </a>
       <a href="#"> banana </a>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm trying to send this `element` to a PHP page using AJAX. Here is my code:

```
  var element;
 element =  $('#element').html();


      $.ajax({
           url:"save.php",
           type:"POST",
           dataType:"json",
          // processData: false,
           data:{element:element},
             success: function(data){
              console.log(data);

           }

       });
```

my **save.php** file

```
 echo $element = $_POST['element'];  // i'm getting {} object why?
```

In my PHP  file i'm getting blank `object` like this `{}`  why I don't know?

**Question:** how to get the HTML element in the PHP page ?

Comment: change dataType:'html'

Comment: why so much negative vote my question is valid one ?

Comment: Hahaha... Votes is based on users moods not for the questions..

Comment: @SudharsanS, yeh you are right but they are blocking me from asking furthur questions

Comment: Later, Downvotes is possible to change upvotes if the question is good...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Sudharsan S in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41162931/im-getting-blank-object-in-php-page#comment69526497_41162931):

```
  $.ajax({
       url:"save.php",
       type:"POST",
       dataType:"html",
      // processData: false,
       data:{element:element},
         success: function(data){
          console.log(data);

    }
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: user5405873 please accept the answer if you got the answer or please comment others could give solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Try this....

```
var element;
 element =  $('#element').html();


  $.ajax({
       url:"save.php",
       type:"POST",
       dataType:"json",
      // processData: false,
       data:{'element':element},
         success: function(data){
          console.log(data);

       }

   });
```

`dataType:"json",` Refers what type of data you want to back from server. So i think this is not major problem.

Your mistake is here

Replace

```
data:{element:element},
```

By

```
data:{'element':element'},
```

Comment: For more details see `javascript` object declaration.